# What is a good resources to add content snippets (widgets) to many sites like iGoogle, Facebook and MySpace, etc

Tags: facebook, widget, myspace, igoogle

I have found services like ClearSpring and Widgetbox for putting content snippets onto a widget range of social networking web sites, but I would like to build my own widgets without a third party dependency. I have been looking but I have not yet found a good resource to learn how to create widgets/gadgets for multiple sites. It was easy to build a gadget for iGoogle, but Facebook, MySpace and the others are less obvious.

What is a good resource to create content snippets for multiple sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually more than just different standards. The context of different networks make it harder to map 1 to 1. Sure there is overlap, but each network has a large delta from each other.

Its managing the delta that's the hard part, not learning the different syntaxes.

In the mobile space there are few products, like OpenFeint and PhoneGap.

Most developers tend to roll their own framework since it is such a volatile space.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that they're converging on two camps:
- FaceBook
- everybody else (using OpenSocial)

your iGoogle widget is OpenSocial, so it's almost ready to be used on MySpace and others.  now go to FaceBook to cover all.